# How to load only a specific section of a requested UIWebView url?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I'm creating an app for a local business, but they're making it a pain for me because they won't and aren't going to create iPhone friendly webpages. They instead requested that I only load a particular section of the webpage.

Is there anyway to do this by specifiying the only allowed coordinates of the webpage that the user can navigate? They want me to only show a few html tables, and want the rest of their desktop webpage with links, etc. out of view to the user. What they're asking for seems a bit 'hackish' to me, but I appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716234/how-to-load-only-a-specific-section-of-a-requested-uiwebview-url"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

   NSLog(@"CNN String is %@",string);


   [self.wv loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];

   [self.wv setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

   NSString *testString = [self.wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"nav-tags\").innerHTML;"];

   NSLog(@"Test String is %@",testString);
}
```

If you put this code, you will see "Tags" as the output. Do the same thing on yours with the proper id.

Comment: So how would I display the filtered div id back into the webview?

Comment: You can always show it in another web view or what ever, by wrapping it with <html></html> tags.

Comment: I tried the code, but when I call `NSString *testString = [self.wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"nav-tags\").innerHTML;"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:nil];` in webViewDidFinishLoad, the webView is thrown into a never ending loading loop.

Comment: No, you are loading it back into the same web view and that is why there is this infinite loop. Create another web view and wv2 and do not have the view controller as its delegate. That way the new wv2 will load the contet and will not call the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working pretty much, but the only problem I have now is when I tap on the refresh button, the page doesn't refresh and I just get a blank page.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I am sure you will figure out the rest. It is a question of understanding UIWebviews, delegate methods etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go about this by creating the app sections in php. So a given page might make several RESTful ajax calls to load content to separate JavaScript view controllers.

Comment: This all needs to be done on the app side, since they aren't willing to change their website or server.

Comment: Hah. Good luck. Sounds like you have some fun XML parsing ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use download the whole web page and use a combination of tricks, like regular expressions etc to get the portion of the web page you want.

It would be easiest if the html page uses css and have created sections as divs with ids. That will make your job easy.

However, this is not easily maintainable since, as soon as the web page is changed, your code may break. Use firebug or some other plugin in firefox and identify the section you want to surface and then go about figuring out a solution. You can also use javascript to get the dom elements and show them in a UIWebview.

Comment: So I would need to request the given url first, store it as a NSString, and then extract what I need based upon what's in a tag I select, such as <tbody></tbody> and then feed that into the UIWebView?

Comment: Please check the website first and see the html source. It is quite possible that they use div ids. In that case, it will be much easier than if you have to use regular html tags, because there can be same tags all over. Infact, if they use regular XHTML compliant page, XML parsing can give you what you want, but most of the html pages are not strict XML and your NSXMLParser will fail if it is not strict XML. It is difficult to propose a solution without knowing the extent of the problem.

Comment: Ok, this is good news I think, but the part I need to 'parse' is wrapped within a unique div id named: `<div id="ctl_ctl_cphBody_cphCenter_divHtml">` The question is, what do I need to do to implement?

Comment: I cannot give you a solution right away, but you would be able to get to it correctly if you research on how to execute Javascript from Objective C. Also find out as to how to inject your javascript into the web page and execute it. Then it is very easy because all you would need to do then is to get the object at the correct hierarchy, or document.getElementByID ... etc. I did it, but do not have the code to help you.

Comment: I just added another answer with the code. Just create a sample view controller, put a webview in a nib and put the code above in that.